# What service to use to send text message to user's phone?

Tags: google-app-maker

Is anybody sending out text messages to user's phones with AppMaker?  If so, would you mind posting your preferred solution that has been tried and works with AppMaker/Google Cloud?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you send text messages via email if you know the phone number and the service provider?

Answer (score 0):

Neither App Maker or App Script or Cloud Platform provide SMS services as first party.

So, you can to make market research, choose service that suits your needs best and then if you have any hurdles making it friends with App Maker come back here and ask more specific question, for instance how to authenticate 3rd party service.